# Apple Math -O Linker warning in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I get the warning `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L "path/to/library"`.
This stared happening after I added a library into project.

I tried clean, build and removing unnecessary paths from `App Target->Build Settings->Library Search Paths`.

None of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below answer on [apple developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/905025#905025).

The bug is due to an error in XCode 5 when it deals with the user adding new files or folders to the project.

Xcode is modifying the `Library Search Paths` build setting, and making a mess of it.
Instead of adding $(SRCROOT)/ it is adding fully rooted paths to all new items, and adding random amounts of /// into other elements of the string.
It also seems to be duplicating source paths in some instances, probably because it's broken the existing ones, and thinks they need adding again.

The solution:

1. Copy out your Library Search Paths string into a text editor.
2. Remove any fully rooted paths that shouldn't be there, and replace them with the usual $(SRCROOT)/MyFiles/ type paths.
3. Remove all extraneous slashes and make sure each path has a " character at beginning and end to protect against spaces in filenames.
4. Paste the edited string back into Build Settings.
5. Clean, then Build. Should be back to normal.